# Sending post parameters to server always Null

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Android development and I am facing problem, I am sending Post parameters to server via Volley but on server i always receive Null values. i am unable to find what i am doing wrong in the code given bellow, please help.

Code is bellow

```
            String postJsonUrl = "https://example.com/activate_dealer.php";
            // Post params to be sent to the server
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
           // params.put("token", DeviceToken1);
            params.put("full_name", fname);
            params.put("mobile", mobile);
            params.put("password", pass);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("city", city);
            params.put("pincode", pincode);
            params.put("address", address);
            params.put("sponsor", sponsor);
            params.put("parent", parent);

            //JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            //        url, params, //Not null.
             //       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()


            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,postJsonUrl, new JSONObject(params),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {



                                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));


                                String loginStatus = response.getString("Lstatus");
                                //String pi = response.getString("pi");

                                //Log.d("nn",nickname);
                                //Toaster.toast(loginStatus);
```

Comment: write your code so we can see whats wrong in your code

Comment: your request accept form data or json request

Comment: It accept Form data

Comment: you are sending in json request

Comment: Thank you Milan, $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 this solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way to send the request

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, postJsonUrl,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("full_name", fname);
            params.put("mobile", mobile);
            params.put("password", pass);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("city", city);
            params.put("pincode", pincode);
            params.put("address", address);
            params.put("sponsor", sponsor);
            params.put("parent", parent);
                        return params;
                    }

                };

                getRequestOtpPage().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);return params;
                    }

                };

            getRequestOtpPage().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to retrieve JSON object instead of $_POST and this solved my problem

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);